# Are dconf values for 'top-panel' and 'bottom-panel' used by Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, panel, dconf

- Gnome Shell 3.6.2
- Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

`/org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/toplevels/bottom-panel` has several options theoretically to customize the behavior of Gnome panels.

I tried to set that the bottom bar is showed faster and that it is automatically hidden. For this I changed the settings as shown below in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I restarted the Gnome environment with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using GNOME or GNOME Classic/Fallback?

Comment: @JeremyBicha From the Q: *"Gnome Shell 3.6.2"*

Comment: You should try to use `gconf-editor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: **no**, they aren't used by Gnome Shell.

The reason is simple: those settings are for gnome-panel and gnome-panel is not part of Gnome Shell, it is part of the so-called Gnome Fallback (or Gnome Classic).

If you want a proof to be 100% sure, download the source code of both gnome-panel and gnome-shell:

```
apt-get source gnome-panel gnome-shell
```

and then look for a property:

```
grep -r unhide-delay
```

You'll see that all results come from the gnome-panel package.